# MYSQL Find a matching item in two arrays

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a date range search for a booking system.  I have one table with a list of resources which can be booked, and another with timeslots which relate to a resource being booked.

TABLE STRUCTURES WOULD BE :

```
RESOURCES 

ID | RESOURCE_NAME 

BOOKED_TIMESLOTS

ID | RESOURCE_ID | TIMESLOT
```

I then need to search through these dates using an array of timeslots.  If one of the dates in the array matches one of the dates in the BOOKED_TIMESLOTS table the resource is removed from the results.  The obvious way would be to loop through the array in PHP, doing multiple DB queries, but I wondered if there was a quicker MYSQL solution.

Comment: MySQL does not support arrray. Please provide structure of your tables

Comment: how do you store the arrays of data in database ? as json ? show us some sample data you have

Comment: This question reads oddly -unless a user is a resource which can be booked.

Comment: Updated to include table structure

Comment: `I need to store an array of dates in mysql as a field in a table of resources.` Either you don't need to do this, or you don't need a relational database

Comment: @Strawberry agreed, I've updated the question.

Comment: If you were to use the loop idea, what would the query for one iteration of the loop look like?